# Using Fixed Positioning on a Vertically Aligned Div

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

Hoping there's a simple solution to this.  Basically what I'm trying to do is place a div (#hello) in the vertical center of the browser *and* use fixed positioning so it doesn't budge on scroll.  Here's my HTML so far:

```
<section id="home">
    <div id="home-container">
        <div id="hello"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the CSS:

```
#home {
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

*:first-child+html #home {
    position: relative;
}

* html #home {
    position: relative;
}

#home-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

*:first-child+html #home-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

* html #home-container {
    position: absolute;top:50%;
}

*:first-child+html #hello {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}

* html #hello {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}

#home {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Right now the div is vertically centered within the "home" section but moves on scroll.  I've tried changing the #home and #home-container to fixed positioning but it doesn't work.

I've searched around quite a bit and apologize if a similar thread already exists.  Hope someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `*` for everything? For example `* html`? You don't know what it does,so understand that first...

Comment: Yeah, it's a code used from a tutorial.  I'll try removing them to see if it helps.

Comment: Stop referring to that tutorial now... can you provide the link

Comment: Here you go: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/center-div-with-dynamic-height/

Comment: Yikes that is crazy.. Don't refer that

Answer (score 0):

The concept for vertically aligning a div to the vertical center with a fixed position would be to add the position:fixed property (specifying the offsets), and then placing a negative margin top of half the div height. Let's say that #hello is 100px tall for example:

```
    #hello {
      position:fixed;
      top:50%;
      margin-top:-50px;
    }
```

With position:fixed; the div will be relative to your document window.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this style. Also you have to add some content in the middle so that you can check properly, or, give some height(in px) to the parent div. An empty parent div with no height will not reflect the change.

```
#hello{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
```

You can check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/76a4j/6/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css with this one

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
html, body{height:100%;}
#home{display:table; margin:auto; height:100%; width:100%; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px;}
#home-container{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;}
#hello{display:inline-block;}
```

I made a fiddle for you. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/fQwFL/

Hope it will fix your problem.